# Access JSON Objects in nested Array with string key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

**I want to get access to a bunch of keys that is nested inside a couple of arrays. The ones we are talking about is all the src keys, inside the media Objects - How do I accomplish that?**

```
"attachments":[
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "url":"https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.1334460356630907&type=1",
            "type":"album",
            "title":"Photos from Rasmus Bøker Christensen's post",
            "target":{
               "url":"https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.1334460356630907&type=1",
               "id":"1334460356630907"
            },
            "subattachments":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821134255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                     "type":"photo",
                     "target":{
                        "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821134255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                        "id":"10155421821134255"
                     },
                     "media":{
                        "image":{
                           "width":720,
                           "src":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p180x540/18194065_10155421821134255_140448089567975329_n.jpg?oh=ea225d9f9117eacf0988c90df99db4ab&oe=599424AA",
                           "height":540
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821149255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                     "type":"photo",
                     "target":{
                        "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821149255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                        "id":"10155421821149255"
                     },
                     "media":{
                        "image":{
                           "width":540,
                           "src":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18157176_10155421821149255_5817407499141479529_n.jpg?oh=44b9765b9db47c2ca24fa39f91c36674&oe=597A78C2",
                           "height":720
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821159255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                     "type":"photo",
                     "target":{
                        "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821159255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                        "id":"10155421821159255"
                     },
                     "media":{
                        "image":{
                           "width":540,
                           "src":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18194059_10155421821159255_3644927739532235006_n.jpg?oh=5b74b2b4e733ff72c9883f4692a7007d&oe=59744F95",
                           "height":720
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

**How would I access the src with An Example like this:**

```
attachments[0].data[0].subattachments.data[0].target.url
```

Comment: You're just assigning a string. It does not even access your nested object.

Comment: what's the problem? What have you tried? And what is it about this snippet `var image = "attachments.[0].data.[0]";`. I'm not sure what you're trying here. Are you trying to assign that object to `var image`? Or does `var image` contain the path you want to access?

Comment: `var image = attachments[0].data[0].subattachments.data[0].target.url` etc ...

Comment: I have tried attachments[0].data[0].subattachments.data[0].media.image.src, but that is not working :/ Any other ideas?

Comment: How is your object named? You started your dump with some property, which evidently belongs to a (unknown) object?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean, but everytime i try to access the src key, I get the error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: You're missing a " before attachments. Otherwise the syntax you specified should work fine. It works on my machine.

Comment: Since you have to fields called data here, you need to figure out which one is failing. try doing it step by step. First try to access `attachments[0].data` , then `attachments[0].data[0]`, etc. See at which point it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of all the `src` properties with this function:

```js
function deepKeyValues(obj, key) {
    return Object(obj) !== obj ? []
        : (key in obj ? [obj[key]] : []).concat(
            ...Object.keys(obj).map( k => deepKeyValues(obj[k], key) ) 
          )
}
// Sample data
var obj = { 
    "attachments":[{
        "data":[{
            "url":"https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.1334460356630907&type=1",
            "type":"album",
            "title":"Photos from Rasmus Bøker Christensen's post",
            "target":{
                "url":"https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=pcb.1334460356630907&type=1",
                "id":"1334460356630907"
            },
            "subattachments":{
                "data":[{
                    "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821134255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                    "type":"photo",
                    "target":{
                        "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821134255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                        "id":"10155421821134255"
                    },
                    "media":{
                        "image":{
                           "width":720,
                           "src":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p180x540/18194065_10155421821134255_140448089567975329_n.jpg?oh=ea225d9f9117eacf0988c90df99db4ab&oe=599424AA",
                           "height":540
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821149255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                    "type":"photo",
                    "target":{
                        "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821149255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                        "id":"10155421821149255"
                    },
                    "media":{
                        "image":{
                            "width":540,
                            "src":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18157176_10155421821149255_5817407499141479529_n.jpg?oh=44b9765b9db47c2ca24fa39f91c36674&oe=597A78C2",
                            "height":720
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821159255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                    "type":"photo",
                    "target":{
                        "url":"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155421821159255&set=gm.1334460356630907&type=3",
                        "id":"10155421821159255"
                    },
                    "media":{
                        "image":{
                           "width":540,
                           "src":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18194059_10155421821159255_3644927739532235006_n.jpg?oh=5b74b2b4e733ff72c9883f4692a7007d&oe=59744F95",
                           "height":720
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }]
};
// Demo
console.log(deepKeyValues(obj, 'src'));
```